# Simple URL rewriting fails

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a very simple aim: Rewrite the URLs of my PHP app such that `localhost/slim_demo/archive` is interpreted as `localhost/slim_demo/index.php/archive` by the system but the user sees the former. **EDIT:** The system is behaving as if no rewriting is taking place. The latter version of the URL returns data, but the former throws a Not Found error.

I used the following `.htaccess` file, but it's not happening (by the way, as the second line says, uncommenting it rejects all requests, which shows that `.htaccess` is alive and kicking):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -Indexes 
#deny from 127.0.0.1 #Uncomment to prove that .htacess is working
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^slim_demo/(.*)$ slim_demo/index.php/$1 [NC,L]
```

And here's the relevant section from my `apache2.conf`:

```
<Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all denied
</Directory>
<Directory /usr/share>
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
<Directory /media/common/htdocs>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I also did `a2enmod rewrite` and `service apache2 restart`. Frustrated, I also added this to my sites-available and did a restart:

```
<Directory /media/common/htdocs/>
        Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes
        AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Not sure what else I need to do!

Comment: Where is your .htaccess located ?

Comment: Do you have an htaccess file in your "slim_demo" directory?

Comment: @Zimmi @Jon Yes, it's in the `slim_demo` directory!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if this .htaccess file is in the slim_demo directory, your [RewriteRule](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) never matches :

> In Directory and htaccess context, the Pattern will initially be
>   matched against the filesystem path, after removing the prefix that
>   led the server to the current RewriteRule

(The pattern is in your case the `^slim_demo/(.*)$` part).

This means that when you try to get the URL `localhost/slim_demo/archive` the `slim_demo` part is removed, and your rule never can match.

So you need:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1
```

but this will bring you in an infinite loop and a 500 error. You must trigger this rule only if the REQUEST_URI does not have the index.php.

All together becomes:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(?!/slim_demo/index\.php).*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: It works! Except that I still don't understand how. Let me read up and post some minor questions in comments? :)

Comment: I'm sorry but why does `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1` cause an infinite loop? Is it because the rule says "redirect everything to after index.php", which means redirect "index.php/page_requested" again to index.php and so on?

Comment: @dotslash The thing to understand for this is best explained in the [Apache doc about the flag L](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l). When you change an URL the work for Apache begins again with a new URL, and if your .htaccess is encountered again, it will be run again. You will then have an infinite loop : /slim_demo/archive => /slim_demo/index.php/archive => /slim_demo/index.php/index.php/archive => etc... If you are with Apache v2.4, there is a new flag 'END' which handles this kind of problems : https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/rewrite/flags.html#flag_end

Comment: Absolutely brilliant explanation! I knew about the `[L]` but was wondering what good it was. Thanks a lot! :D